# Spring Data Hibernate save silently fails

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot application with spring-boot-data-jpa.

Everything works fine: Session management, account management, relations between those objects, etc...

I want to add a new entity to log account actions for the users, yet as soon as i try to save it, it doesn't. Keep in mind all other dao's from spring session and account management work, and are identically implemented. (the spring session one is the automatic implementation.

```java
@Entity
@Table(indexes = [Index(columnList = "username")])
open class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: UUID? = null

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    lateinit var type: EventType

    var username: String = ""
    var addr: String = ""
    var port: Int = 0
    var date: Date = Date()
}

enum class EventType {
    LOGIN, LOGOUT, LOGIN_FAIL, CERT_GEN
}
```

the repository:

```java
@Repository
interface EventRepository: JpaRepository<Event, UUID>
```

the service:

```java
interface IEventService {
    fun onLogin(request: HttpServletRequest, username: String)
    fun onLogout(request: HttpServletRequest, username: String)
    fun onLoginFail(request: HttpServletRequest, username: String)
    fun onCert(request: HttpServletRequest, username: String)
}
```

the impl:

```java
@Service
@Transactional
open class EventService : IEventService {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var eventRepository: EventRepository


    override fun onLogin(request: HttpServletRequest, username: String) {
        val evt = Event()
        evt.addr = request.remoteAddr
        evt.port = request.remotePort
        evt.username = username
        evt.type = EventType.LOGIN
        eventRepository.save(evt)
    }
... same with different EventType
```

here is the trace log of the transactions from transactional and hibernate.

```java
2018-07-01 14:59:06.685 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [com.acme.services.impl.EventService.onLogout]
2018-07-01 14:59:06.685 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
2018-07-01 14:59:06.685 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .i.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl : Opening Hibernate Session.  tenant=null, owner=org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@7f512e36
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Opened session at timestamp: 15304499466
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Setting flush mode to: AUTO
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Setting cache mode to: NORMAL
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Transient instance of: com.acme.dbo.Event
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Saving transient instance
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 DEBUG 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Generated identifier: b3619aa5-af5c-4552-a092-187d0d16e94b, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Saving [com.acme.dbo.Event#b3619aa5-af5c-4552-a092-187d0d16e94b]
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Adding an EntityInsertAction for [com.acme.dbo.Event] object
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityInsertAction[com.acme.dbo.Event#b3619aa5-af5c-4552-a092-187d0d16e94b]]
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Adding resolved non-early insert action.
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [com.acme.services.impl.EventService.onLogout]
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Closing session
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@14babdc8]
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Releasing JDBC resources
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl   : Closing logical connection
2018-07-01 14:59:06.686 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl   : Logical connection closed
2018-07-01 14:59:06.699 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .i.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl : Opening Hibernate Session.  tenant=null, owner=org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@15a4558c
2018-07-01 14:59:06.699 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Opened session at timestamp: 15304499466
2018-07-01 14:59:06.699 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Setting flush mode to: AUTO
2018-07-01 14:59:06.699 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Setting cache mode to: NORMAL
2018-07-01 14:59:06.747 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Closing session
2018-07-01 14:59:06.747 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@610769c]
2018-07-01 14:59:06.747 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Releasing JDBC resources
2018-07-01 14:59:06.747 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl   : Closing logical connection
2018-07-01 14:59:06.747 TRACE 3128 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl   : Logical connection closed
```

i use these service in handlers like this one, added into the HttpSecurity with `http.logout().addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)`:

```java
@Component
open class AcmeLogoutHandler : LogoutHandler {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var service: IEventService

    override fun logout(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, authentication: Authentication?) {
        service.onLogout(request, authentication?.name ?: "")
    }
}
```

i am quite desperate trying to figure this one... No errors, yet it doesn't work, and anything i try to do seems to fail.

One notable thing though is that when i use `eventRepository.saveAndFlush(evt)` instead of `eventRepository.save(evt)` it throws a `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress`
despite the log clearly showing a transaction is currently loaded. Maybe this is the key to the issue.

UPDATE:

I found a case that works with that exact code. Simply run it is the traditional endpoint/service layer. The problem is definitely with accessing the database from the handlers.

Comment: does your `EventService` needs to be `@Transactional`?

Comment: No, but it doesn't work either without, the jpa repository implementation is transactional anyways.

Comment: and shouldn't you use `protected open lateinit var service: IEventService` when using `@Autowired` (not a Kotlin expert)

Comment: i don't use open on any @Autowired and they all work correctly. The issue is not code not executing, as you can see in the log the process happens down to the hibernate level, it then simply does not show up in the database.